# Tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory even though directory exists

Tags: makefile, tar

I've created a temporary directory in a Makefile:

export TMP := $(shell mktemp -d -t), do a bunch of work there. Then I want to create a tarball.

> tar czf ../packages/$(PACKAGE).lin.tar.gz -C $(TMP) $(PACKAGE).lin

The issue is that this command always gives

Tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

I've added a test to see if the directory exists using this right before the tar:

if [ -d $(TMP)/$(PACKAGE).lin ]; then echo "Dir exists"; fi

I see the echo, the directory does exist. I also cannot cd into that directory!?

Also, it seems to be dropping the latter part of the directory name...it will say cannot stat'$(PACKAGE)' instead of '$(PACKAGE).lin'.

If I do this:

> cd $(TMP)
>
> > tar czf ../packages/$(PACKAGE).lin.tar.gz $(PACKAGE).lin

Then it will say cannot stat $(PACKAGE).lin.

Comment: Does `../packages` exist relative to the directory you're calling `tar` from?

Comment: @Bandrami I create that directory using "mkdir -p ../packages" a few commands before.

Comment: We can't debug this based on the info here.  Please show the _real_ make rule, not just parts; please show the way that the relevant variables are set including PACKAGE, please show the actual error messages that are printed, and the other output you see.  Please copy/paste them _exactly_ rather than retyping them.  Even minor changes in the output are big clues.  Also please use StackOverflow formatting so that it's easy to see what's output, etc.  Also specify what operating system you're using and what version of `tar` you're using.